# Set no. of copies in a System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog

Tags: c#, wpf

For what I searched so far, I could not find a way to preset the number of copies in a System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog, which is the one used in WPF. I cannot fallback or use another one because I need the PrintVisual method that only this class offers (afaik)
Unless there is another way, I'm thinking of doing a for loop and call the dialog.PrintVisual() method for the number of desired copies.I have not tested yet, but I'm quite sure it should work. My question: Is this the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for `dialog.PrintTicket.CopyCount`.

[Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printticket.copycount.aspx).

Comment: Need to add a reference, in the project, to the ReachFramework assembly in order for the Intellisense to recognize .CopyCount